# How to set reminders in excel by calculating dates in header columns

Tags: vba, excel

Good day!

I am using one of the tutorials: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x2_y0_KDaN0 and this is what I need with a few changes.

Here, The clients are listed in column A and the subsequent columns have dates and what interaction has been done with the client. If client xyz is in cell A2, cell b1 and onwards have dates of the months and cells b2, c2, d2 etc have either informed or pending entered. I want excel to set a reminder if the client contact is overdue beyond one week. The cells input chosen as "informed" indicates a contact that is made. I need to pick up the last date that the contact happened and calculate the dates. If the result is greater than or equal to 7, then a reminder should show. I would like to insert a column after the client name which the cell highlights and indicates a text as a reminder.

I have used the following code:

```
Sub dates()

End Sub
Dim x As Long
For x = 2 To informedendcolumn
Dim informedendcolumn As Integer
Dim mydate1 As Date
Dim mydate2 As Long
Dim date1 As Date
Dim date2 As Long

informedendcolumn = Range("2:2").Find(what:="informed", after:=Range("A1"),      searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Column

mydate1 = Cells(informedendcolumn.ListObject.Range.Row, informedendcolumn.Column).Value
 mydate2 = mydate1

date1 = Date
date2 = date1

If date2 - mydate2 = 7 Then
Cells(x, 2) = "Yes"
Cells(x, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
Cells(x, 2).Font.ColorIndex = 2
Cells(x, 2).Font.Bold = True

End If
Next

End Sub
```

Cant really get where in going wrong. There are no errors but the code doesnt run.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you (try to) run the code? By the way -- you have a stray `End Sub` towards the start of the code -- this code has a syntax error, so of course it can't run.

Comment: `informedendcolumn.Column` doesn't look right?? think you just need `informedendcolumn = Range("2:2").Find(what:="informed", after:=Range("A1"),      searchdirection:=xlPrevious)` and check `informedendcolumn ` has found something, also `InformedColumn` is defined after it's use.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs,,, have corrected the end sub and tried the above method. Nothing works as yet...